# Anchoring to an element with a javascript hash router

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, handlebars.js, anchor, router

I'm using `Parse-SDK-JS`, `Handlebars.js` and hash routing to create a dynamic webpage. When a user clicks on any link, I call a template using a URL in the following way: `http://www.website.com/#/admin`.

**Router**

```
BlogApp.Router = Parse.Router.extend({

        start: function () {
            Parse.history.start({root: '/beta/'});
        },

        routes: {
            '': 'index',
            'blog/:url': 'blog',
            'category/:url': 'category',
            'admin': 'admin',
            'login': 'login',
            'reset': 'reset',
            'logout': 'logout',
            'add': 'add',
            'register': 'register',
            'editprofile': 'editprofile',
            'changeprofilepic': 'changeprofilepic',
            ':username': 'userprofile'
        },

        index: function () {
            BlogApp.fn.setPageType('blog');

            $blogs = [];

            if (!currentUser) {
                Parse.history.navigate('#/register', {trigger: true});
                console.log("There is no logged in user.");
            } else {
               var groupId = currentUser.get('groupId');
               var designsQuery = new Parse.Query(BlogApp.Models.Blog).equalTo('groupId', groupId).include('author').descending('lastReplyUpdatedAt').limit(50);
               designsQuery.find({success: function (blogs) {

                for (var i in blogs) {
                    var des = blogs[i].toJSON();
                    des.author = blogs[i].get('author').toJSON();
                    $blogs.push(des);
                }
                // console.log(blogs);

                BlogApp.fn.renderView({
                    View: BlogApp.Views.Blogs,
                    data: {blogs: $blogs}

                });
            }, error: function (blogs, e) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            }}); 
           }
       },
});
```

**View**

```
BlogApp.Views.Blogs = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#blogs-tpl').html()),
        className: 'blog-post',

        render: function () {
            var collection = {blog: []};
            collection = {blog: this.options.blogs};
            this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
        },
    });
```

My problem is that upon loading a new template, the user is not sent to the top of the page, i.e. to the following div:

```
<div id="main-nav"></div>
```

The users' scroll position on the page doesn't change if the new page is longer than the current page. The user just ends up somewhere down the middle of the page because the new template is loaded but they are not anchoring anywhere new.

Normally in `HTML` I would open a new page to a particular anchor with something like this: `http://www.website.com/page#container` if I wanted to, but with the way I set up my hash routing the anchor *is* the template call itself, so I can't do something like this: `http://www.website.com/#/admin#container`.

I hope this makes sense.

How can I always send the user to the div "container" upon loading a new template into my view?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by scrolling into an element after the View was generated.

```
        cookies: function () {
            BlogApp.fn.setPageType('cookies');
            BlogApp.fn.renderView({
                View: BlogApp.Views.Cookies
            });

            document.getElementById('main-nav').scrollIntoView();
        },
```

Better... by adding the scrollIntoView() function after data is rendered into the View object, so that this works for all links in the router without so much copy pasta.

```
BlogApp.fn.renderView = function (options) {
        var View = options.View, // type of View
            data = options.data || null, // data obj to render in the view
            $container = options.$container || BlogApp.$container, // container to put the view
            notInsert = options.notInsert, // put the el in the container or return el as HTML
            view = new View(data);
            view.render();
            if (notInsert) {
                return view.el.outerHTML;
            } else {
                $container.html(view.el);
                document.getElementById('main-nav').scrollIntoView();
            }
        };
```